# Why can't I grep this way?

Tags: sed, grep

I would like to change the line "disable = yes" to "disable = no"  into the following file :

```
[root@centos2 ~]# cat /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
service tftp
{
    ...
    server_args             = -s /var/lib/tftpboot
    disable                 = yes
    per_source              = 11
    ...
}
```

I tried this :

```
[root@centos2 ~]# grep 'disable                 = yes' /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
[root@centos2 ~]#
```

by just copying the space with my mouse but it doesn't grep anything...

Why and how can I know what are the elements between "disable" and "=" ? Is it several spaces? tabulations?

I know I can grep using the following regex :

```
[root@centos2 xinetd.d]# grep -E 'disable.+= yes' /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
    disable                 = yes
[root@centos2 xinetd.d]#
```

And finaly, is there a better way of replacing "yes" by "no" using sed than the following :

```
[root@centos2 xinetd.d]# sed -r 's/disable.+= yes/disable                 = 
no/g' /etc/xinetd.d/tftp

service tftp
{
    ...
    server_args             = -s /var/lib/tftpboot
    disable                 = no
    per_source              = 11
    ...
}
```

EDIT :

Result of the od command thanks @ilkkachu

```
[root@centos2 xinetd.d]# < /etc/xinetd.d/tftp grep disable | od -c
0000000  \t   d   i   s   a   b   l   e
0000020                                       =       y   e   s  \n
0000037
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The spaces are more commonly known as "whitespace", and can include not just spaces but tabs (and other "blank" characters). In a regular expression you can often refer to these either with `[[:space:]]` or `\s` (depending on the RE engine) which includes both *horizontal* (space, tab and some unicode spacing characters of various width if available) for which you can also use `[[:blank:]]` and sometimes `\h` and *vertical* spacing characters (like line feed, form feed, vertical tab or carriage return). `[[:space:]]` is sometimes used in place of `[[:blank:]]` for its covering of  the spurious carriage return character in Microsoft text files.

You cannot replace with `grep` - it's just a searching tool. Instead, to replace the `yes` with `no` you can use a command like this:

```
sed '/disable\>/s/\<yes\>/no/' /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
```

This tells `sed` to substitute (change) the word `yes` into `no` on any line that contains the word `disable`. (The `\>` (initially a `ex`/`vi` regexp operator), in some `sed` implementations, forces an end-of-word (though beware it's not *whitespace-delimited-words*, it would also match on `disable-option`)). Conveniently this sidesteps the issue of whitespace altogether.

---

Be careful: with a line such as `eyes yes`, an unbounded `yes` substitution would apply to the first instance of `yes` and leave you with `eno yes`. That's why I have used `\<yes\>` instead of just `yes`.

Comment: It is well explained but doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Pozinux I didn't see that your `disable` was not at the beginning of a line. I've amended my RE accordingly.

Comment: Still no change sorry.

Comment: @Pozinux, are you expecting it to modify the file in-place? This command doesn't do that -- it just writes new contents to stdout. (In-place changes require either some extra scripting to write to a temporary file and rename it, or a nonstandard/nonportable option such as `-i`).

Comment: @Pozinux, ...it's also possible you have a `sed` without the `\<` and `\>` extensions, though they're quite widespread, so that would be surprising.

Comment: I know that it doesn't modify in-place (I should use -i option to do that) but my stdout is not modify.

Comment: You're right, actually -- I can reproduce that. `sed '/disable\>/s/\<yes\>/no/' <<<'    disable                 = yes'` doesn't work for me either (on MacOS, with BSD sed). The OP's original code works fine for me with GNU sed (v4.4), though.

Comment: Which version of `sed` are you testing with? Since you're on CentOS, it would seem likely that you'd have GNU sed, with which the answer works, as opposed to BSD sed, with which it doesn't.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2 on Centos 7.4

Comment: Ho wait! Didn't see the first @roaima comment saying that it edited the command... So I confirm it is working. Thanks also CharlesDuffy

Comment: Was going to say -- works fine for me with `docker run -i centos:latest sed '/disable\>/s/\<yes\>/no/' <<<' disable = yes'`

Comment: Knowing the file structure, I could just simplify into `sed '/disable/s/no/yes/' /etc/xinetd.d/tftp`

Comment: @Pozinux yes, you could and that would work perfectly for this specific instance.

Answer (score 6):

> Why and how can I know what are the elements between "disable" and "=" ? Is it several spaces? tabulations?

Probably tabs. You could use something like

```
< /etc/xinetd.d/tftp grep disable | od -c
```

to see. It will show tabs as `\t`, and spaces as spaces.

Comment: Didn't know about od command, very nice! I edited my question so that you can see the result of the od command. If I understand, there are no tabs between the "disable" and the "=" is this right? But how many? Can we count them?

Comment: @Pozinux, so no tabs then. I can't see any reason why that first `grep` shouldn't work, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try grep alternative called **sift** from [sift-tool.org](http://sift-tool.org) - is grep on steriods that does intelligent regex pattern matching

Comment: How would that work in this situation? Can you give an example?